# Redirect non-www subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

Using these directives, I can redirect any `non-www` subdomain to the `www` subdomain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

What I need to achieve is to redirect the `www` subdomain only.

For example I want to redirect only `blog.myname.com` to `www.blog.myname.com`. The rule in the config above will redirect `blog.myname.com` to `www` but it also redirect `myname.com` to `www.myname.com`, which is not what I am looking for. I also need to redirect all queried subdomain not just blog.myname.com

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to achieve that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www)[^\.]*)\.myname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%1.myname.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Above code withh redirect all subdomains but will not effect `myname.com` or `www.myname.com`.

Comment: actually your code redirect all subdomain.myname.com to www.myname.com thanks for trying to help me :)

Comment: That's what you wanted right when you wrote: `I also need to redirect all queried subdomain not just blog.myname.com`

Comment: actually what I meant by that is to redirect all queried non www subdomain to www subdomain. For example *.myname.com redirect to www.*myname.com. but it's ok now I got it working. Thanks again :)

Comment: Good that you got it working. I updated my answer for future visitors in case they're looking for similar answers.

Comment: I decide to use your directive because it's much simpler :) thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.myname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.blog.myname.com{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hey thanks. I need to remove {REQUEST_URI} to got it to work. May I ask how do I redirect all subdomain and not just blog.myname.com? I will update the question.